# Android OnLongClickListener not firing on MapView

Tags: java, android, google-maps, mobile

I just registered an OnLongClickListener on my my MapView on an Android app I'm currently writing. For some reason however the onLongClick event doesn't fire.

Here's what I've written so far:

```
public class FriendMapActivity extends MapActivity implements OnLongClickListener {
    private static final int CENTER_MAP = Menu.FIRST;
    private MapView mapView;
    private MapController mapController;
    //...
    private boolean doCenterMap = true;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.friendmapview);
        this.mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map_view);
        this.mapController = mapView.getController();

        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.displayZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setLongClickable(true);
        mapView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                //NEVER FIRES!!
                return false;
            }
        });

        //...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_3:
            mapController.zoomIn();
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1:
            mapController.zoomOut();
            break;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        int actionType = ev.getAction();
        switch (actionType) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            doCenterMap = false;
            break;
        }

        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

        ...
}
```

May overlays which I'm adding cause the problem?? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the mean time I found the "solution" (or workaround, call it as you like) by myself. The way I worked through this issue is by using a GestureDetector and forwarding all touch events to that object by implementing an according OnGestureListener interface.

I've posted some code on my blog if anyone is interested:
http://juristr.com/blog/2009/12/mapview-doesnt-fire-onlongclick-event/

Don't ask me why this didn't work by hooking up the OnLongClickListener directly on the MapView. If someone has an explanation let me know :)

**UPDATE:**
My previously suggested solution using a GestureDetector posed some drawbacks. So I updated the blog post on my site.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem and there is a simple solution to your problem actually; it's because you're using the wrong type of listener.

You should use the `OnMapLongClickListener()` object from the `OnMapLongClickListener` interface.

Hopefully everything should work properly :)
Please tell me if it works.

Comment: Maybe this is something they have introduced on a later version. I can't remember to have seen such an event at the time I was implementing this functionality.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this problem.  I tried the solution above, but it doesn't *quite* work 100% in that we want the long press action to fire, even if the user is still holding a finger down.

This is how I implemented a solution, using a handler and a delayed task -
As a side note, I used a similar type implementation, but in reverse, to hide/show zoom controls on touch/etc..

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

private final Runnable mTask = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // your code here
    }
};

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        // record the start time, start the timer
        mEventStartTime = ev.getEventTime();
        mHandler.postDelayed(mTask, LONG_PRESS_TIME);
    } else if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        // record the end time, dont show if not long enough
        mEventEndTime = ev.getEventTime();
        if (mEventEndTime - mEventStartTime < LONG_PRESS_TIME) {
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mTask);        
        }
    } else {
        // moving, panning, etc .. up to you whether you want to
        // count this as a long press - reset timing to start from now
                    mEventStartTime = ev.getEventTime();
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mTask);
                    mHandler.postDelayed(mTask, LONG_PRESS_TIME);
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In WebView framework code performLongClick() is used to handle long press event, this is how Android copy Text Feature is implemented in Browser, that is why onLongClick is not been fired.