# How to create a Context Menu on a MapView?

Tags: android, android-mapview, contextmenu

I would like to have a Context Menu on my `MapView` and let the user choose between a map or a satellite photo in the background. I have tried to create a Context Menu by following [Creating Menus](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) but it doesn't work for me.

The application works but no Context Menu is shown. How can I create a Context Menu on my `MapView`?

In my `onCreate()` I have this code:

```
    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    registerForContextMenu(mapView);
```

And I have overrided some methods:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo info) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, info);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.map_view_item: 
        return true;
    case R.id.satellite_item: 
        return true;
    default: return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that normal long-click processing does not work well with `MapView`, perhaps due to the way it handles touch events. [There](http://juristr.com/blog/2009/12/mapview-doesnt-fire-onlongclick-event/) are [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678493/android-maps-how-to-long-click-a-map) [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831490/android-onlongclicklistener-not-firing-on-mapview) if you really need the functionality.