# What is the keyboard shortcut of long press in Android Emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am wondering what should be the keyboard shortcut of long press in Android emulator? I have a list of items. I have created a function to delete an item if long press over the item. But I can't test in my emulator. If I press the mouse for long time still it's triggering click event.

Comment: I don't know keyboard shortcut, but you should check your code. Because long click with mouse ***is*** long press/ tap in emulators.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please see your code because long click with mouse is long press/ tap in emulators.

Comment: make sure you remember to add the long click listener to your button.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you remember to add the long-click listener to your button.

Example:

```
//without lambda
button.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {   
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button Long Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });

//using lambda
button.setOnLongClickListener(v -> {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button Long Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    });
```

[As seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156753/android-i-dont-understand-long-press-detection-in-my-subclass-imageview)