# Android - Element with Touch and Click events

Tags: java, android, events, click, touch

I'm having problems trying to make an element respond differently when there is action like "click" or type "touch". When I click on the element (is a simple listener, not worth paste the code), it performs the action perfectly, but completely ignores the action of touch. That way I could associate the element to distinguish the two events?

Should I apply the listener to the children of the view that the action is executed?

Thanks.

**Edit**

Resolved!

Added a check on the use of the touch event before calling it.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    if (this.onTouchEvent(event))
        return this.onTouchEvent(event);
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: There is a `setOnTouchListener` for most Views. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, I tried to do it. But it ignored the touch event too and only the click event was listened.

Comment: Make sure that you return true from the onTouch method, otherwise you only get one event for ACTION_DOWN.

Comment: The program is still ignoring the event "touch". The method is performed by dragging any corner of the screen, unless the button with the click event... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831490/android-onlongclicklistener-not-firing-on-mapview) thread for help, or use the [answer](http://juristr.com/blog/2009/12/mapview-doesnt-fire-onlongclick-event/) straight away.
Good luck =)

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        // record the start time, start the timer
        mEventStartTime = ev.getEventTime();
        mHandler.postDelayed(mTask, LONG_PRESS_TIME);
    } else if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        // record the end time, dont show if not long enough
        mEventEndTime = ev.getEventTime();
        if (mEventEndTime - mEventStartTime < LONG_PRESS_TIME) {
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mTask);        
        }
    } else {
        // moving, panning, etc .. up to you whether you want to
        // count this as a long press - reset timing to start from now
                    mEventStartTime = ev.getEventTime();
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mTask);
                    mHandler.postDelayed(mTask, LONG_PRESS_TIME);
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Comment: I understand your code. But the program don't execute the method when I click on the buttons (with OnClickListener).

Comment: can you post the whole class?
I suspect your listener is set on the class rather than the button